# How to calculate checksum of a file efficiently

Tags: go

I want to efficiently calculate the checksum of a very large file (multiple GB). This Go program has two approaches one chunks the file and calculates the checksum `quicksha` but it's not correct. Another classical approach `slowsha` works well.

Can you help me fix `quicksha`?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/pprof"
    "os"
)

func slowsha(fname string) {
    f, err := os.Open(fname)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    h := sha256.New()
    if _, err := io.Copy(h, f); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%s %s", hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil)), os.Args[1])
}

func quicksha(fname string) {
    f, err := os.Open(fname)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    buf := make([]byte, 16*1024)
    pr, pw := io.Pipe()

    go func() {
        w := bufio.NewWriter(pw)
        for {
            n, err := f.Read(buf)
            if n > 0 {
                buf = buf[:n]
                w.Write(buf)
            }
            if err == io.EOF {
                pw.Close()
                break
            }
        }
    }()
    h := sha256.New()
    io.Copy(h, pr)
    log.Printf("%s %s", hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil)), os.Args[1])
}

func main() {
    fname := os.Args[2]
    choice := os.Args[1]

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        if choice == "-s" {
            slowsha(fname)
        } else if choice == "-f" {
            quicksha(fname)
        } else {
            log.Fatal("Bad choice")
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
shasum -a 256 lessthan20MBTest.doc >> reference answer
d91b998a372035c2378fc40a6d0eee17b9f16d60207343f9fc3558eb77f90b71  lessthan20MBTest.doc

./quicksha -f lessthan20MBTest.doc >> wrong answer
b97d5167bbe945ca90223b7503653df89ba9e7d420268da27851fca6db3fcdcf lessthan20MBTest.doc

./quicksha -s lessthan20MBTest.doc . >>> right answer
d91b998a372035c2378fc40a6d0eee17b9f16d60207343f9fc3558eb77f90b71  lessthan20MBTest.doc
```

Comment: Can you explain why you believe that quicksha should work and is faster than slowsha?

Comment: `io.Copy` already uses a buffer, what are you expecting to get out of reimplimenting `io.Copy` yourself?

Comment: I am new to this and I was myself trying to figure it out. Although, the implementation after calculating SHA it may need to POST this file for multiple services, getting benefited from multiwriter, teereader. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems in your program:

First: you are already using a buffer for reading/writing, so there is no need to use a `bufio.Writer`. You are double-buffering with that. Which also happens to be the reason why you don't get the result you want: you have to `w.Flush()` before closing the pipe, because you haven't written what's in the `bufio.Writer`'s buffers to the pipe:

```
if err == io.EOF {
    w.Flush()
    pw.Close()
    break
}
```

Second: you are making your buffer shorter. In general, `read` does not have to read to fill the buffer. If the underlying stream is a network stream, `read` may read less than the buffer size, and that doesn't mean the end of stream reached. For files, this does not make any difference in practice but in general, you should do:

```
if n > 0 {
    w.Write(buf[:n])
}
```

Third: Did you measure? It is unlikely that the 'faster' implementation is actually faster. Including the buffering in `io.Copy`, you're triple-buffering with this implementation.

Comment: I see, I get this file as a chunk (packet) on the server and the server calculates the checksum. With this implementation, I am trying to avoid full file reassembly. What do you recommend to optimize this?

Comment: `h:=sha256.New()`, write each chunk with `h.Write()`, then get `h.Sum()`. You don't need to reassamble the file.

Comment: Thanks, all that works, how do I POST to third party service(s) without additional buffering. I am trying to use ```teereader``` and ```multireader``` as I understand them.

Comment: Maybe you can ask that as a separate question with more context.